# Print text and then change colour using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, colors

I was wondering if it is possible to change the colour of my text inside the `<a>`...`</a>` tags, from black to red after a certain time interval and remain permanently red.

```
do {
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML +="<a>Hello World</a><br>";
  await sleep(...)
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML +="<a>Hello World</a><br>";
  await sleep(...)
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML +="<a>Hello World</a><br>";
  await sleep(...)
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML +="<a>Hello World</a><br>";
} while {...}
```

and after this code runs, it should change the first "Hello World" from black to red, then the second "Hello World" will print and change that text colour from black to red, and so on...

I have explored different methods on this matter...

```
a {
    animation: change 1s step-end both;
}

@keyframes change {
    from { color: black }
    to   { color: red }
}
```

but what I found to be the problem with this method is that it constantly changes from black to red and back on all the text containing the  tags, and the colour change does not remain permanent.

Comment: So you want your `<a>` to stay red even after a reload ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, no not after a reload, my text is initially black and after the print statement....there's a delay (2s)... then the text turns red. After the reload the text should turn back to it's initial colour.

Answer (score 0):

don't use @keyframes.
because keyframes works in a loop.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, is there an loop-free version of keyframes?

Comment: Why don't you use setTimeout() method to do this.

Comment: you can easily change the color using this. i think @keyframe can't be stopped in between. it will run atleast one and will show the initial situation again( in your case black color).